# Mono stack/heap corruption on Ubuntu causes segmentation fault

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono

I have a C#, multi-threaded, TCP server app running on Mono. It's the same app that runs on over 100 servers for the last 4 years without any problems. I compile that app on Windows then load it onto the Ubuntu machine and run it..

it works great!

However, on two new servers hosted with [OVH](https://www.ovh.com) (via [OneProvider](http://oneprovider.com)) the process only runs for about 20 mins at a time before Mono crashes with the following error:

```
mono-0 (err): =================================================================
mono-0 (err): Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
mono-0 (err): a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
mono-0 (err): used by your application.
mono-0 (err): =================================================================
```

Before mono crashes I trap an exception in the app and output it to the console, the exception is always different and always very strange. For example a null object exception in String.Format or a null object exception when setting a class level enum value (this == null??)

Example 1

```
mono-0 (out): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
mono-0 (out):   at System.String.FormatHelper (System.Text.StringBuilder result, IFormatProvider provider, System.String format, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
mono-0 (out):   at System.String.Format (IFormatProvider provider, System.String format, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
mono-0 (out):   at System.String.Format (System.String format, System.Object arg0, System.Object arg1) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
mono-0 (out):   at server.handleClinet.logConsole (System.String msg) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Example 2

```
mono-0 (err): Unhandled Exception:
mono-0 (err): System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
mono-0 (err): Parameter name: obj
mono-0 (err):   at server.handleClinet.set_ConnState (ConnectionState value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
mono-0 (err):   at server.handleClinet.doConnect (System.Object p) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
mono-0 (err):   at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
mono-0 (err): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
mono-0 (err): Parameter name: obj
mono-0 (err):   at server.handleClinet.set_ConnState (ConnectionState value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
mono-0 (err):   at server.handleClinet.doConnect (System.Object p) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
mono-0 (err):   at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

In this case `ConnState` is an enum, this is the line:

```
ConnState = ConnectionState.Starting;
```

As far as I can tell there is no situation that .NET should crash with a string formatting exception or with this setting enum value.

It seems to me something is stepping on mono's memory and whole stack is getting screwed up.

**The question is, what is it about these two specific servers that causes the problem?** They are running the same setup as all other servers, Ubuntu (14.04.2), with the same version of Mono (3.2.8) and the same compiled .net app.

We have reloaded the servers several times with fresh Ubuntu installs with no luck. We have tried various version of Mono and tried targeting different versions of the framework (3.4 + 4). The crash changes slightly with different errors but the results is always the same.

System load and memory are all fine at the time of the crash. The two machines have 32GB of ram, mono when running only uses about 100mb. There is also plenty of disk space available (1.7TB).

Comment: If this is new hardware, it sounds like it's faulty.  Have you run the in-BIOS memory test?

Comment: I don't know if the hardware is new but it's a fairly decent spec so I don't think they are very old. OneProvider assures me that the hardware is fine and the strange thing is that it happens on both machines hosted in the same data center. All other apps appear to run fine, but to be fair there isn't much else on it

Comment: It could even be a concurrency problem... different machines, different concurrency problems

Comment: @xanatos you mean some sort of thread concurrency issue? possible I suppose but the app is pretty well tested, runs with thousands of clients connected (per instance) on over 100 servers without any problems.. just on these two OVH servers..

Comment: @antfx Is the number of processors different? (if you use VM to run your program, the number of processors is set in the VM, so for example your hundred of servers could be configured to be "mono-processor" or "dual-processor" while your new VM could have more processors)

Comment: @xanatos the number of processors vary from server to server, they are nearly all physical dedicated servers (not VM). Some older servers (4+years old) have one processor with maybe 2 cores, while newer ones have upto 8 cores. The two servers in question each have 4 logical processors.

Comment: Found the issue for those interested. It was a bug introduced into the linux kernel: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1450584

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a bug introduced into the kernel from `3.13.0-48` onwards.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1450584

We have rolled back to `3.13.0-30` for until `3.13.0-54` is released and the crashes have stopped.